# TypeError: CalcularSalario() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Titulo'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ao tentar criar um Código simples em Python e me deparei com o seguinte erro no método de calcular salario

> TypeError: CalcularSalario() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Titulo'

```
class Professores():
    ID = 0
    Nome = "João Das Neves Negras"
    Titulo = "dr"
    Formacao = "Cientista da computação"
    DataNascimento = "22/09/1998"
    Email = "joaodasnevesnegras@ifgoiano.com.br"
    NumDisciplinas = 10

    def pegarID(self):
        return self.ID

    def pegarNome(self):
        return self.Nome

    def pegarTitulo(self):
        return self.Titulo

    def pegarFormacao(self):
        return self.Formacao

    def pegarDataNascimento(self):
        return self.DataNascimento

    def pegarEmail(self):
        return self.Email

    def pegarNumDisciplinas(self):
        return self.NumDisciplinas

    def DefinirID(self, id):
        self.ID = id

    def DefinirNome(self, nome):
        self.Nome = nome

    def DefinirTitulo(self, Titulo):
        self.Titulo = Titulo

    def DefinirFormacao(self, Formacao):
        self.Formacao = Formacao

    def DefinirDataNascimento(self, DataNascimento):
        self.DataNascimento = DataNascimento

    def DefinirEmail(self, Email):
        self.Email = Email

    def DefinirNumDisciplinas(self, NumDisciplinas):
        self.NumDisciplinas = NumDisciplinas

    def CalcularSalario(self):
        salario = (400 * self.NumDisciplinas)
        if(self.Titulo == "me"):
            return salario + salario*0.3
        if(self.titulo == "dr"):
            return salario + salario*0.5
        else:
            return salario

prof = Professores()

prof.DefinirID(1)
print('ID: {}'.format(prof.pegarID()))
print('Nome: {}'.format(prof.pegarNome()))
print('Titulo: {}'.format(prof.pegarTitulo()))
print('Formação: {}'.format(prof.pegarFormacao()))
print('Data de nascimento: {}'.format(prof.pegarDataNascimento()))
print('Email: {}'.format(prof.pegarEmail()))
print('Número de disciplinas: {}'.format(prof.pegarNumDisciplinas()))
print('Salario: {}'.format(prof.CalcularSalario()))
```

Comment: Rodei seu código aqui e obtive o erro *AttributeError: 'Professores' object has no attribute 'titulo'*, que indica que na linha 56 você utilizou `self.titulo` ao invés de `self.Titulo`. Fora isso, rodou (sem erros).

Answer (score 1):

Por que tu colocou esses atributos como estáticos? Não seria mais lógico colocar ele num método **init**? Tipo Assim:

```
class Professores():
    def __init__(self,ID,nome,Titulo,Formacao,DataNasc,email,NumDisc)
        self.ID=ID
        self.Titulo=Titulo
        self.Nome=nome
        self.Formacao=Formacao
        self.DataNascimento=DataNasc
        self.Email=email
        self.NumDisciplinas=NumDisc

    def pegarID(self):
        return self.ID

    def pegarNome(self):
        return self.Nome

    def pegarTitulo(self):
        return self.Titulo

    def pegarFormacao(self):
        return self.Formacao

    def pegarDataNascimento(self):
        return self.DataNascimento

    def pegarEmail(self):
        return self.Email

    def pegarNumDisciplinas(self):
        return self.NumDisciplinas

    def DefinirID(self, id):
        self.ID = id

    def DefinirNome(self, nome):
        self.Nome = nome
```

E outra coisa: Você vai colocar seus atributos como privados? Por isso essa funções get? Por que do contrário, elas são desnecessárias. Pelo o que eu sei, no python os métodos e atributos são públicos por default

Answer (score 1):

Ao executar o seu código o erro que foi levantado foi o seguinte:

> AttributeError: 'Professores' object has no attribute 'titulo'

Isso está acontecendo porque os objetos de sua classe não contém nem o atributo 'titulo', nem nenhum dos atributos que você deseja. Para fazer com que os objetos de sua classe tenham os atributos desejados você deve criá-los dentro do método `__init__`. Sua classe corrigida seria mais parecida com isso:

```
class Professor:
    def __init__(self, id, nome, titulo, formacao, data_nascimento, email, num_disciplinas):
        self.id = id
        self.nome = nome
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.formacao = formacao
        self.data_nascimento = data_nascimento
        self.email = email
        self.num_disciplinas = num_disciplinas

    def calcular_salario(self):
        salario = 400 * self.num_disciplinas

        if self.titulo == 'me':
            return salario + salario * 0.3
        elif self.titulo == 'dr':
            return salario + salario * 0.5
        else:
            return salario


prof = Professor(1, 'João Das Neves Negras', 'dr', 'Cientista da computação', '22/09/1998', 'joaodasnevesnegras@ifgoiano.com.br', 10)

print('ID: {}'.format(prof.id))
print('Nome: {}'.format(prof.nome))
print('Titulo: {}'.format(prof.titulo))
print('Formação: {}'.format(prof.formacao))
print('Data de nascimento: {}'.format(prof.data_nascimento))
print('Email: {}'.format(prof.email))
print('Número de disciplinas: {}'.format(prof.num_disciplinas))
print('Salario: {}'.format(prof.calcular_salario()))
```